# What determines the ending you get in Milky Way Prince?

Tags: milky-way-prince-the-vampire-star

I recently finished my first playthrough of Milky Way Prince and want to go back for the alternate endings. The "Life of a Star" chart in the pause menu indicates there are three different endings. However, when I played the game a second time I got the same ending despite making different choices.

I found a [list of choices](https://www.gamepretty.com/milky-way-prince-the-vampire-star-walkthrough-with-100-achievements/) you can make to get the different endings, but they list every single choice regardless if it has anything to do with the ending. It doesn't explain which choices actually have an impact on the ending you get.

**What determines the route you get when approaching a branch in Milky Way Prince?**

[image: Star map]

Comment: I accidentally found a hidden branch that can [kick you off the neutral route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwtRp.jpg).